# Set repetitive alarm between exact times in a day

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm working on an application in Android and I need to create a reminder which will run everyday from 09:00 to 22:00 (Let's say once in an hour or once in two hours) until I cancel it. I have a code below where I create a reminder with the given exact date and with the given id. So in that way I can cancel the reminder later on with the defined id.

Any Idea how to do it ?

```
    public void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int alarmId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);           
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, intent, 0);
        // Get the AlarmManager service
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, when you receive the alarm in your BroadcastReceiver, then set another one for an hour later, or whatever interval you want.  If that next alarm would be beyond 22:00, then make it for 09:00 the next day.  A repeating alarm would not work for what you proposed, so just use set like you did in the example you gave.

Comment: I'm working on a reminder application and this is just one type of reminders in this project. I will have different types of reminders so I cant just add one hour as a next alarm. I need to know exactly that this is the alarm that needs to run daily. So I need to find way to create this alarm without controlling it all the time in Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: You can add extras to the Intent that you create the alarm with.  You could put something in the Intent that will tell the BroadcastReceiver what to do with the alarm, or pass that info on to whatever Activity or Service that the BroadcastReceiver launches and handle it there.

Comment: It doesn't seem a good idea because I will have plenty of different alarm types and I need to control it all the time in the background. instead of that I can create for example 10 different alarms with 24 hours interval time. What do you think ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding completely what you're trying to do.  Can you give an example of three different alarm types that you'll have?

Comment: I have five different Reminder types (e.g. Water, Medicine...).This will be the water reminder. Application with notify user every two hours about this type of reminder until the user cancel this reminder. and in the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver I will push a notification a sound. That's what I'm working on currently.

Comment: I would do it by having a constant int for each reminder type, WATER, MEDICINE, etc.  When creating the intent for the alarm, I'd add that constant as an extra:
`intent.putExtra( "type", WATER );`

The BroadcastReceiver would read that extra and take the appropriate action based on the type, including setting a new reminder alarm.  When the receiver cancels the reminder, I'd remove the alarm with AlarmManager.cancel.

Comment: thanks for the answer,  it seems possible I will try it soon.